# 3D Involute of constant geodesic/ Gauss curvatures

Tags: differential-geometry

Is my following  proposition correct?

Unwinding a  taut surface-contacting  geodesic thread to trace an involute with constant  geodesic curvature $ k_{g}$ is possible *only* on  $ \mathbb R^2 $ surfaces of constant Gaussian curvature K.

If so, can it be proved in general?

EDIT1:

I obtained the result $ k_{g} = \sqrt {|K|}$, not to be confused with $ \tau_g $ of Beltrami-Enneper theorem.

EDIT 2/3:

The radius of curvature is measured along the taut geodesic arc *on the surface* that connects $ \gamma(t) $ to another point of involute *on surface* with unwound length equaling arc distance.

Comment: Are you assuming that the surface is embedded in flat $\mathbb R^3$ and unwinding the geodesic there?

Comment: An R^2 surface with K > 0 or < 0 in 3-space.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the curvature of an involute always the reciprocal of the arc length of the original curve from the start point to the current point of tangency? Thus it can't be constant.

Comment: That is true in the plane only, but not *always*. In 3D it is interestingly tricky.

Comment: x @Naras: Hmm, right.

Comment: I'm confused. If $\gamma(s)$ is your curve on the surface, you want to trace out the curve $\psi(t) = \gamma(t)+t\gamma'(t)$? And measure its curvature in ambient space?

Comment: So to find the point $\psi(t)$, you 1) start at $\gamma(t)$; 2) move in the tangent direction off of the manifold to $\gamma(t)-t\gamma'(t)$; 3) project (using the ambient metric) to the closest point back on the manifold?

Comment: I used scalar curvatures without parametrization in 3D.The way you suggest is like the tangential developable which surely will leave the surface. Perhaps not this way to go with a *single parameter* $t$ to describe a two parameter manifold but I can be wrong.

Comment: @user7530:The radius of curvature is measured along a geodesic arc on the surface.